# Change Command+Period Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I would like to change the Terminal interrupt keyboard shortcut to ideally Command+Shift+C.  Just this shortcut solely.

Is there a feasible way to do this?

Comment: I have used **^C** for as long as I've use computers to preform a terminal interrupt, didn't know about **⌘.** however, since they apparently do the same thing, I believe for this purpose my answer accomplishes the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following was created, tested and works for me in **macOS High Sierra**.

---

**Create the Automator *service*...**

In **Automator**:

1. **File** > **New**, or press: **⌘N**
2. Select **Service** and click the **Choose** button.
3. Configure the settings as shown in the first image below.
4. Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*.
5. Replace the default *code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.
6. Save as e.g.: **My Terminal Interrupt**

[image]

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using control down
```

---

**Assigning the keyboard shortcut...**

In **System Preferences**...

- **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** add **⇧⌘C** (press Shift-Command-C) to the **My Terminal Interrupt** *service*, as shown in the image below.

  - Note: A word about the shortcut you assign... **⇧⌘C** is offered as a suggestion however, you'll need to select one that doesn't conflict with Terminal (or any other app that has focus if setting the *service* to **any application**) when pressed. This may require a strange combination or a four character combo. **⇧⌘C** worked fo me in **Terminal** after changing the default for the **Show Colors** *command*, shown further below.

[image]

---

**Terminal** already uses **⇧⌘C** for the **Edit** *menu* > **Show Colors** *command*, so you'll need to change that to e.g. **^⇧⌘C** (Control-Shift-Command-C).

**Changing the default keyboard shortcut...**

- **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

  1. Click the `[+]` button
  2. Change **Application:** from **All Applications** to: **Terminal**
  3. For **Menu Title:** type: **Show Colors**
  4. For **Keyboard Shortcut:** type, e.g.: **^⇧⌘C**
  5. Click the **Add** button.

[image]

[image]

---

Now when in **Terminal** and I need to interrupt a running *command*, I press **⇧⌘C** instead of **^C** 
 (or **⌘.**) to stop the process.

Comment: Unfortunately in High Sierra there appears to be a a bug that prevents this keyboard shortcut from working consistently for some reason in Terminal(works 1 out of every 10 presses).  I am going to do some more investigation but at this point this doesn't work.  I have tried a range of shortcuts thinking maybe something else would work but unfortunately it hasn't.

Comment: @William, Just curious, why not just use the builtin **^C** manually (or **⌘.** which actually sends a **^C**)?

Comment: @William, As I said, "The following was created, tested and works for me in **macOS High Sierra.**", and I just now tested it again over 20 times and it worked every time. There is a slight lag compared to pressing **^C** manually (or **⌘.** which sends a **^C**). I will say though that in every OS I've ever used sometimes the interrupt is not immediately caught and I've had to press **^C** again, so I can imagine that this workaround might be slower to act especially if whatever process is running is hogging CPU cycles to the point even pressing **^C** manually might not act quickly.

Comment: I type on Dvorak and can't feasible hit that shortcut with one hand.

Comment: My High Sierra is not updated so it might be an older version of High Sierra.

Comment: I updated and this seems to working fairly consistently now.